# How to add column with number of occurances in dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, duplicates

I have a dataframe in R with many rows that are duplicate:

| header1 | header2 |
| --- | --- |
| tuna | apple |
| orange | salmon |
| orange | trout |
| blue | trout |
| orange | salmon |
| tuna | apple |

As you can see, rows 1 & 6 and 2 & 5 are exact duplicates of each other.

I would like to remove the duplicates, but create a third column where it lists the number of occurrences:

| header1 | header2 | NEW: Number of Occurances |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tuna | apple | 2 |
| orange | salmon | 2 |
| orange | trout | 1 |
| blue | trout | 1 |

Does anyone have an idea for how I can do this? I'm really stuck. Any help is much appreciated.

---------
[I did take multiple shots at it. I don't think they're close to being correct, but here's what I was trying]:

```
countx = 1
county = 2

while (county <= 6){
  if ((df[countx,] == df[county,]) == T & T){
    print("true")
  } else {
    print ("false")
  }
  county <- county+1

}
```

However this will return "true" even if only one of the columns matches another one – for instance, "orange" in row 2 and "orange" in row 3, even though the other cell in the row doesn't match.

I was also trying an if else, but don't really know where to take it:

```
if(duplicated(df[1,])==T){
  xx
}else{
  xx
}
```

As you can tell, I'm a self-taught newbie trying to use R for my thesis and getting a bit in over my head. Would really appreciate any help! TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to simply use `count` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  count(header1, header2)
```

**Output**

```
  header1 header2 n
1    blue   trout 1
2  orange  salmon 2
3  orange   trout 1
4    tuna   apple 2
```

Or with `tally`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(header1, header2) %>%
  tally() %>% 
  ungroup
```

Or another option with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[, list(count =.N), by=list(header1, header2)]
```

Or you can use `ddply` from `plyr`:

```
plyr::ddply(df, c("header1", "header2"), nrow)
```

**Update**

If the order does not matter for the 2 columns, then you could do something like this, where we first split each row into its own dataframe in a list. Then, we can `sort` the 2 columns and collapse into one string for each row, then we can count occurrences using `table`, then convert back to a dataframe.

```
split(df2, seq(nrow(df2))) %>%
  sapply(., function(x)
    unlist(x) %>% sort() %>% paste(collapse = " ")) %>%
  table(combo = .) %>%
  data.frame
```

Or we can also use `tidyverse` by making use of `purrr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% 
  pmap_dfr(~list(...)[order(c(...))] %>% set_names(names(df2))) %>%
  group_by_all %>% 
  count
```

*Output*

```
          combo Freq
1    apple tuna    3
2    blue trout    1
3 orange salmon    2
4  orange trout    1
```

*Data*

```
df2<- structure(list(header1 = c("tuna", "orange", "orange", "blue", 
"orange", "tuna", "apple"), header2 = c("apple", "salmon", "trout", 
"trout", "salmon", "apple", "tuna")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

#  header1 header2
#1    tuna   apple
#2  orange  salmon
#3  orange   trout
#4    blue   trout
#5  orange  salmon
#6    tuna   apple
#7   apple    tuna
```

Comment: Thank you so much AndrewGB and @PaulS, however I think there's a complication: some of the rows have the same data, but in different order. For instance, 

| tuna | salmon | 

while another row is 

| salmon | tuna |

Grouping the data with the above methods doesn't identify that they're the same. Is there perhaps an edit to the code that could solve this?

Comment: @AlecMax Yes, that is definitely doable. I've added a couple of options at the bottom with base R or with `tidyverse`. Essentially, the idea behind both solutions is to sort the 2 columns so that the order is the same in each row, then we can count occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(header1, header2) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = "drop")

#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   header1 header2     n
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <int>
#> 1 blue    trout       1
#> 2 orange  salmon      2
#> 3 orange  trout       1
#> 4 tuna    apple       2
```